# What type to give a JSON object

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, typescript, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following form

```
 using (Ajax.BeginRouteForm(
   ...
                new AjaxOptions
                {
                    HttpMethod = "POST",
                    OnFailure = "OnFailure",
                    OnSuccess = "OnSuccess"
                }))
            {
                ..,.
            }
```

I implement the `OnSuccess` function in a TypeScript file.  I am trying to make this function more TypeScripty.  At the moment I have this

```
function OnSuccess(data: what type goes here?) {
...
// use data.SomeValue here
...
}
```

Question is what type shall I say data is such that I can still somehow use data.SomeValue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `any` type:

```
function OnSuccess(data: any) {
    ...
    // use data.SomeValue here
    ...
}
```

Comment: But that's the same as not using any parameter at all.  I wanted to be a bit more specific.

Comment: How can you be more specific if you don't know the type? Or if you do, simply define it and use it.

Comment: The question is, is there some way to say "this is a JSON object with x, y and z properties"?

Comment: Yes, you could declare a class containng the desired properties.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is with an interface, because you make an explicit assertion of the structure of the object returned and communicate very clearly what the callback expects.

```
export interface IOnSuccessArgs {
    propertyA: string;
    propertyB: number;
}


function OnSuccess(data: IOnSuccessArgs): void {
   // ... data has propertyA and propertyB

}
```